# bash in windows error?

Tags: bash, cygwin, sh

I'm trying to execute a very simple script with cygwin, composed of:

```
#!/bin/bash\n
echo "hi"\n
```

with `cygwinpath\bin\bash.exe /cygdrive/c/my_path/test.bash`

but it says

```
/cygdrive/c/my_path/test.bash: line 1: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

However, it still prints 'hi'.

Why is this, and how to fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the `\n` from the first line where you have `#!/bin/bash\n` it should just be `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: The \n is just here to show I'm not using \r\n, but it is not written in the file, it's just a regular carriage return in linux

Comment: Looks like your path could be messed up then?  Mine is `/cygdrive/c/<my_path>/bin/bash.exe`

Comment: I tried putting the full path, it doesn't work either: "/cygdrive/c/test.bash: line 1: #!/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/bash.exe: No such file or directory"

Comment: Might be due to the encoding of your file (UTF-8 with BOM): https://superuser.com/questions/484041/run-shell-script-on-windows-using-cygwin

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your script should just be `#!/bin/bash` and not `#!/bin/bash\n`

The code is still executing because the heading `#!/bin/bash` specifies a shell, and `echo "hi"\n` is a command to the terminal.

As for your issue I'm having no problems running it using the following path in the cygwin terminal:

```
/cygdrive/c/<my_path>/bin/bash.exe /home/user/test.bash
```

Comment: I just added the trailing \n to point out that, even though I'm using windows, I don't have \r\n but rather just \n.